# How to auto-start MongoDB on CentOS reboot?

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, automation, mongodb

How do I setup MongoDB so that it will start back up automatically after a server reboot? This is on CentOS 5.5.

I start it with the following command, but if the server reboots, I have to login to SSH and run that again to get it going (not that big of a deal really, but would be nice to know that this isn't necessary if I don't have access to the server).

> ./mongod --config ./mongodb.config
>   --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best bet is to install the rpms provided by 10gen (makers of mongodb)

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CentOS+and+Fedora+Packages

That will install a init.d script for you that you can run

//mongod service

```
chkconfig mongod on
```

Comment: The community edition binaries of MongoDB don't support SSL so I wouldn't consider "install the rpms" to be a "best bet". To be suitable for anything but tinkering MongoDB must be re-compiled with SSL enabled. @larsks answer is better for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an "init script" to start the service when the system boots.  A quick Google search for "writing init scripts redhat" will turn up several useful references.  This seemed like a reasonable start:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html

If you want a quick-and-dirty solution, you can simply add your command to the end of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, which gets executed after all the other init scripts have completed.